# Error in preview of classification in QGIS

Tags: qgis, land-classification, image-classification

While doing LULC classification I am facing the following problem in QGIS. I am unable to do the following process. After selecting all the training inputs, I select classification in band-processing to select class id or macro id to see the preview or to run the classification. Neither I can do the preview or run classification. [image]

Comment: Please paste the error message as text rather sreenshot.

Comment: @Padmanabha following is the error message, pasted in three comments:

Error Message
2024-02-24T23:19:27     CRITICAL    SCP : covariance matrix
2024-02-24T23:19:29     CRITICAL    SCP : multiprocess: error classification
2024-02-24T23:19:29     WARNING    Python error : An error has occurred while executing Python code: See message log (Python Error) for more details.
Python error
plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 572, in create_preview
              apply_class_symbology(cfg.classification_preview, macroclass)

Comment: File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\interface\classification_tab.py", line 135, in apply_class_symbology
              cfg.utils.classification_raster_symbol(
              File "C:\Users/User/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\SemiAutomaticClassificationPlugin\core\utils.py", line 286, in classification_raster_symbol
              classification_layer.dataProvider(), 1, class_list
             AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'dataProvider'
OGR

Comment: 2024-02-24T23:18:29     WARNING    Cannot open C:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp/semiautomatic_classification/remotior_sensus_0110sx8vn8v4/t20240111_213945549673_10000.gpkg ().()